# Frama-C/WP/ACSL Correct use of \valid on structures

Tags: c, static-analysis, design-by-contract, frama-c

I'm having some doubts on how to correctly use the \valid annotation on structs.

```
struct someStruct{
    int size1;
    int size2;
    char *str1;
    char *str2;
}
```

A correct predicate to verify memory safety of the struct would be:

```
/*@
    predicate validStruct(struct someStruct *p) =
       \valid(p) && 
       \valid(p->str1+(0..((p->size1)-1))) && 
       \valid(p->str2+(0..((p->size2)-1)));
@*/
```

or

```
/*@
    predicate validStruct(struct someStruct *p) =
       // 16 bytes: 2 int * 4 bytes + 2 pointers* 4 bytes.
       // Although may depend on implementation and system arch
       \valid(p+(0..15) &&   
       \valid(p->str1+(0..((p->size1)-1))) && 
       \valid(p->str2+(0..((p->size2)-1)));
@*/
```

The first example assumes that `\valid(p)` (where `p` is a pointer to a structure) ensures memory safety on the structure it points to, whereas the second I must specify the range (taking into account the size of the memory fields) manually

Looking at the Stack example in [ACSL by Example](http://www.2shared.com/document/uaOSFjCx/ACSL-by-Example.html) (page 125). They adopt the first example. However in many places `\valid(some_string+(0..strlen(some_string)))` is used to ensure memory safety on those specific memory locations.

**EDIT:**

In response to the answer given. A correct memory safety predicate for this (taken from stdio.h)

```
struct _IO_file {
    int _IO_fileno;     /* Underlying file descriptor */
    _Bool _IO_eof;      /* End of file flag */
    _Bool _IO_error;    /* Error flag */
};
typedef struct _IO_file FILE;


struct _IO_file_pvt {
    struct _IO_file pub;    /* Data exported to inlines */
    struct _IO_file_pvt *prev, *next;
    char *buf;      /* Buffer */
    char *data;     /* Location of input data in buffer */
    unsigned int ibytes;    /* Input data bytes in buffer */
    unsigned int obytes;    /* Output data bytes in buffer */
    unsigned int bufsiz;    /* Total size of buffer */
    enum _IO_bufmode bufmode; /* Type of buffering */
};
```

would be, for ex:

```
/*@

predicate valid_FILE(FILE *f) = 
    \valid(f) && f->_IO_fileno >= 0;

predicate valid_IO_file_pvt(struct _IO_file_pvt *f) = 
    \valid(f)
    // buffer offset
    && f->buf == (char *)f + ((sizeof(*f) + 4*sizeof(void *) - 1)
                                        & ~(4*sizeof(void *) - 1))
    // 16K
    && f->bufsiz == 16384
    && 0 <= f->ibytes <= f->bufsiz
    && 0 <= f->obytes <= f->bufsiz
    && valid_FILE(&(f->pub))
    && (f->next != \null ==> \valid(f->next))
    && (f->prev != \null ==> \valid(f->prev))
    // 16384 + 32 (ungetc_slop)
    && \valid(f->buf+(0..(f->bufsiz+32-1)))
    // data points to address in valid buffer region
    && f->buf <= f->data < (f->buf + f->bufsiz + 32)
;
@*/
```

Comment: Regarding your `valid_IO_file_pvt` predicate, I guess that the line `f->buf == (char *)f + ((sizeof(*f) + 4*sizeof(void *) - 1) & ~(4*sizeof(void *) - 1))` is meant to say that the buffer is adjacent to `f` itself, modulo alignment constraints. There are two issues here. First, I don't think that there is a Frama-C plugin that can take advantage of it. Second, the size of `void *` is undefined (`gcc` set it to `1`, but not all compilers do).

Comment: sizeof `void *`is 4 or 8 bytes on 32 bit or 64 bit machines, respectively.

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. I should have paid more attention to that little `*` after `void`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1 is clearly the good one, as it abstracts over the memory layout chosen by your compiler, and by Cil within Frama-C.

Solution 2 is in fact incorrect as written. Your range `p+(0..15)` must be understood using pointer arithmetics on objects of type `struct someStruct`, and you are in fact requesting that `p` points to an area where `16 * sizeof(struct someStruct)` bytes are valid.

A correct reformulation of solution 2, for standard memory layouts, would have been

> \valid(((char*)p)+(0..15))

In fact, the ACSL reference manual explicitly mentions the following equivalence page 56. (I have removed labels for clarity.)

> \valid(p) <==> \valid(((char*)p)+(0..sizeof(*p))

For strings, the cast `(char*)p` becomes superfluous, as strings are already pointers to char. Thus, writing `valid(p+(0..strlen(p))` requires that `p` points to a memory are where `strlen(p)+1` bytes are valid -- but only because `p` has type `char*`, and `sizeof(char)=1`.

Comment: I still do not understand why i can do the second approach on strings but not on structs

Comment: Solution 2 works on C strings because they are in fact pointers to char. I have added a paragraph to explain this better. Hopefully this should clear things up.

Notice that the file `share/libc/__fc_string_axiomatic.h` defines a predicate `\valid_string` that is a (often useful) shortcut to the definition used in ACSL by Example.

Comment: Ok, i didn't look closely to the citation from the ACSL reference manual. I've edited my question with a more objective example.

Comment: Is this the same for the `\separated` clause? ie (on the first example): `\separated(p, p->str1+(0..((p->size1)-1)))` to guarantee that memory for the string does not overlap with the structure itself

Comment: Your formalizations of valid_FILE and valid_IO_file_pvt seem good. A few remarks, which I hope might be helpful:
- it would be more general to define your predicates directly on the struct type, instead of on "pointer to struct": with your current formalization, you can express properties on \result
- I suggest you drop the property `f->buf == `, which only holds for one implementation, and that you use a `\separated` clause instead

Comment: Your \separated clause is correct wrt. to the semantics of \separated.